# Textbox not retaining its value after postback using a calendar extender

Tags: asp.net, textbox, postback, calendarextender

I'm using CalendarExtender with a textbox as the target control. My code is below:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textBoxFromDate" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" />
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="textBoxFromDate_CalendarExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True"
                    TargetControlID="textBoxFromDate" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" EnableViewState="true">
</asp:CalendarExtender>
```

So I use the calendar control to set the value within the textbox. This works fine, however when a postback happens on the page the textbox value is reset to the default date for the calendar control.

How can I get the textbox to retain its value on a postback?

Thanks in advance.

I'm using ASP.Net 4.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

did you try setting readonly field dynamically rather than in markup ? Also i'd make sure you are not resetting the value in `Page_Load()` during postbacks.

Or what about trying somehting like this on `Page_load` , also checking to see if there is a valid date in box before attempting to set it to the calendar extender selected date ?

```
if (IsPostBack) 
{ 
    MyCalendarExtender.SelectedDate =
        DateTime.ParseExact(MyTextBox.Text, MyCalendarExtender.Format, null); 
}
```

Comment: To be honest I don't need ReadOnly set. It's only there at the moment because of the blogs I've been reading to try to fix this. I've taken it out and the same happens. I don't do anything on the Page_Load after a postback.

Comment: Yes, your 2nd edit works fine for me. Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: Clever.  It worked for me too.  I was planning to introduce some asp:UpdatePanels to reduce the number of full page refreshes (IsPostBack=false -> IsPostBack=true).  I may still add one, or more, but not to solve this problem :)